# Bash glob expanding to multiple arguments

Tags: bash, scripting, wildcards

I am new to bash scripting. I've got a script to ping multiple machines that "I" wrote :

```
for var in "$@"
do
        ping -c 1 -W 2 "$var" > /dev/null
        echo $var = $?
done
```

What I'd like to do is allow a glob as an input to ping multiple machines of similar names.

For instance: `pingall machine[:01-06:]` but I am rather lost on how to accomplish this.

Answer (score 3):

*globbing* is another name for *filename generation* or *pathname expansion*.

That's the process that converts shell wildcards into the list of files that match them. It can only  be used for *existing* files.

Here, you could use brace expansion instead:

```
pingall machine{01..06}
```

Which the shell expands to `machine01`, `machine02`... `machine06` separate arguments regardless of whether files by that name exist in the current directory (it is not globbing).

That syntax is from `zsh` and is also supported by recent versions of `bash` and `yash -o braceexpand`.

With `ksh93`, you'd use:

```
pingall machine{1..6%02d}
```

though in this particular case, you could also use:

```
pingall machine0{1..6}
```

With the GNU `seq` command, you could also do (assuming the default value of `$IFS`):

```
pingall $(seq -f machine%02.0f 6)
```

Answer (score 1):

Patterns expand only when matching file names. Maybe you can use brace expansion instead? Run the script with

```
pingall machine0{1..6}
```

which will be expanded to

```
pingall machine01 machine02 machine03 machine04 machine05 machine06
```